# Am I loopy or is it localstorage...?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage

My goal: To clean up localstorage, by removing previously used items with a `for` loop.

Usually, I have a number of items, like so:

```
order-1356666288243 => {"cartID":2713329701836,"productName"...
order-1356666288243 => {"cartID":2713329701836,"productName"...
```

When I check how many items there are altogether, I get the correct zero-based amount:

```
console.log( localStorage.length );
```

Even when I do a `for loop` to write out the key and values, and `console.log()` a few other things, all is well:

```
for(var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<=len; i++) {

    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    console.log(key + " => " + value);


        if(key != '' && key != null){

            console.log( key.indexOf('order-') );
            console.log(i + '. Key: ', key);

            if(key.indexOf('order-') != -1){
                console.log('The key to be removed is: ', key.toString());
                localStorage.removeItem(key.toString());
            }
       }

    console.log(i + ': ' + len);
}
```

Everything pretty much does what one would expect. However, this line executes **only once** when I run the script:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

or

```
localStorage.removeItem(key.toString());
```

In fact, I have to run the entire script as many times as there are items. So if I have, say 3 items, I need to run the loop 3 times to get rid of each item.

I'm perplexed: Where did I go wrong? All the `console.log()` stuff shows up 3 times (if I have 3 items and run the `for loop` once) . Out of despair, I even changed `i < len` to `i >= len`, but that doesn't solve the problem either.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying a collection while you are traversing it. Always be careful when you do this.

In this particular case, the length of `localStorage` changes when you remove an item, so you end up skipping items.

You should either traverse `localStorage` *backwards* (last item to first item), or better yet you should do this in two passes: one pass to collect the keys to remove, and another pass to remove them:

```
Object.keys(localStorage)
.filter(function(key){return key.indexOf('order-')===0})
.forEach(localStorage.removeItem, localStorage);
```

Or if you need this to work in IE8 or FF3.x:

```
var delkeys = [], key, i, len;
for (i=0,len=localStorage.length; i<len, key=localStorage.key(i); i++) {
    if (key.indexOf('order-')===0) {
        delkeys.push(key);
    }
}
for (i=0,len=delkeys.length; i<len, key=delkeys[i], i++) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. Thank you. I will try this out just for the heck of it. Much appreciated.

Comment: PS: Absolutely amazing! I will need to start looking into this approach and start using it more often. Thank you for showing me that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that when you remove an item, it changes the length of the local storage. Try iterating from the length-1 down to 0 instead of from 0 up to the length. (By the way, the loop condition should have been `i < len`, not `i <= len`. With my suggestion, of course, it should be `i >= 0`.)

Comment: I should elaborate: when you remove an item, the remaining items move down, so whenever you remove an item you are skipping the next one. So an alternative to iterating backwards is to execute `i--;` every time you decide to remove the item at key `i`. This lets the next iteration of the loop catch the item whose key moved into the slot you just emptied.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Hoop. After a bit of noodling around, I came up with the following replacement for the `for loop`: 
    var i = localStorage.length;
    while(i--){

Answer (score 1):

The loop should count down to prevent problems with deleted keys altering storage length.  Try this for loop instead:

```
for( var i = localStorage.length; i--;){
//make sure to remove references to len in your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was at that point, but maybe I did it wrong, since I had no luck with that approach, but I will test it one more time, just to make sure. Thank you. (PS: Just tested it, and that works. Thank you.)